# Erro em página de edição de dados

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

boa noite! Estou com uma página para edição dos dados de usuário que esteja logado naquele momento na conta, porém, estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro da página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Eis o código php da página:**

```
<?php
    include("../banco/conexao.php");

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $nomeUsuario = $row['nomeUsuario'];
        $cpfUsuario = $row['cpfUsuario'];
        $usuario = $row['usuario'];
        $emailUsuario = $row['emailUsuario'];
        $senhaUsuario = $row['senhaUsuario'];


    }
    if(isset($_POST['salvar'])) { 
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $nomeUsuario = $_POST['nomeUsuario'];
        $cpfUsuario = $_POST['cpfUsuario'];
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $emailUsuario = $_POST['emailUsuario'];
        $senhaUsuario = $_POST['senhaUsuario'];

        $query = "UPDATE usuario SET nomeUsuario = '$nomeUsuario', cpfUsuario = '$cpfUsuario', usuario = '$usuario',
        emailUsuario = '$emailUsuario', senhaUsuario = '$senhaUsuario' WHERE id = $id";
        mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Usuário Editado com Sucesso!');</script>";
        echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=pagUsuario.php">';
        exit;

        header("Location: pagUsuario.php");
    }

    }

?>
```

E a linha 61, onde ele está dizendo que contém o erro:

```
<form action="editarPerfilUsuario.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="">
```

Estou com dificuldades, pois é um projeto da faculdade e estou fazendo juntamente com outros colegas, mas até eles mesmos estão com problemas em entender, alguém poderia dar uma help?

Answer (score 0):

seu erro é a falta do método, a página espera receber os dados via POST, com exceção do id que iria via GET.

```
<form action="editarPerfilUsuario.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
```

leia sobre formulários em HTML:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp